# How to set a default wait for Alert with Capyabara?

Tags: ruby, capybara

In my code I don't want to use sleep. How do I use wait_until.

```
########### my code ###############33

     btn_logout.click
     sleep 3
     page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
accept_alert do
  btn_logout.click
end
```

It'll wait for the modal as long as the max wait time that is set for Capybara.

Comment: @Tadeu and if you want to adjust the maximum wait time for just this call you can specify it via a `wait` parameter, as in most Capybara methods, `accept_alert(wait: 20) do ...`.  Generally if you find yourself calling driver specific methods (page.driver.browser...) you're doing something wrong